# creating and querying a collection in another collection. mongodb node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there a way to create and query a collection thats inside another collection... 
Can any one direct  me to literature that can teach me how to do this? 
I've checked the mongodb 
docs tutorial and i havent come across this scenario
  No code example because i don't know where to start.

Here is what im trying to do.

Im modelling  an online shop.  So shop object details are in a collection holding many shops. 
Now each shop has got products and each product its own unique details.  I want to a void using references and rather append but from tutorial from mongodb docs its not quite clear how to do it.

Im fairly new to mongodb 
Thanks.

Comment: "a collection thats inside another collection" This makes no sense to me. That's like saying a table that's inside another table. Are you referring to [subdocuments](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#read-operations-subdocuments)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any such thing as a collection inside another collection with mongo.  A collection is a collection of documents.

There are a couple of ways to link documents to other documents, or collections of other data.  The correct one to choose is up to you, your data, and your application.

- Any document can point to another ObjectId from any field
- You can have an array inside a document
- Combine the two, and you can have an array of document ids

Mongo is a document store, not a relational database.  My suggestion is don't try to use it as a relational database.  If what you need is an RDBMS, use one.

Arrays:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-array/
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

ObjectId:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/

Comment: Thanks i think i have been searching the wrong stuff. Now with this info il give a try.

Comment: @user3119679 if this answers your question then mark this as the answer so this is closed